# Firefox WebExtension : check if extension already exists

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm porting my Chrome extension to a Firefox WebExtension, so far so good, I manage to communicate smoothly with my content, background scripts and my executable.

I would like now to check the existence of my extension. This is actually the way I do it :

> Browser script

```
// browser-script.js

var isExtensionHere = false;

$("#is-extension-here").click(function(){

    console.log("Check the existence of the extension");

    window.postMessage({
        direction: "from-page-script",
        message: "areYouThere"
      }, "*");
});

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.source == window &&
      event.data.direction &&
      event.data.direction == "from-content-script") {
        if(event.data.message == "OK") {
            isExtensionHere = true;
        }
  }
});
```

> Content Script

```
// content-script.js

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.source == window &&
      event.data.direction &&
      event.data.direction == "from-page-script") {

    if(event.data.message == "areYouThere") {
        window.postMessage({
        direction: "from-content-script",
        message: "OK"
      }, "*");
    }
  }
});
```

It works fine when the extension is here. But when it is not, obviously I don't get an answer from my extension. How can I know then how to trigger a popup or a message when the extension is not here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can reverse the logic: make the page listen for a ping from the extension. You need to be mindful of when scripts execute (e.g. depending on `run_at` parameter) in relation to each other, so that you don't accidentally send a message before the page starts listening.
2. You can use another method of announcing presence to the page: a content script can add an invisible DOM element with a known ID, and you can check for its presence from the page.
3. If you want to keep the current approach, you can set a timer for the response to happen. Something like, say, 200ms should be more than enough.

   You can implement this as a Promise, since it can only be resolved once:

   ```
   var isExtensionHere = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const listener = (event) => {
       if (
         event.source == window && event.data.direction
         && event.data.direction == "from-content-script"
         && event.data.message == "OK"
       ) {
         resolve(true);
       }
     }

     setTimeout(() => {
       window.removeEventListener("message", listener);
       resolve(false); // Will have no effect if already called with true
     }, 200);

     window.addEventListener("message", listener);

     window.postMessage({
       direction: "from-page-script",
       message: "areYouThere"
     }, "*");
   });

   // Sometime later
   isExtensionHere.then((result) => { /* ... */ });
   ```

   If you want to dynamically re-check, make `isExtensionHere` a function that returns a new Promise every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and exhaustive answer!